# Visual Studio no me muestra las funciones

Tags: javascript, array, visual-studio, funciones

tengo la siguiente consulta. Le estoy pasando a una función un array de nombres para manipularlo con las funciones básicas. El tema es que cuando quiero ver las funciones correspondientes a la manipulación de arreglos, no me aparece ninguna y solo aparece eso correspondiente a la imagen.
[image: Funciones no aparecen]

Yo esperaba ver algo a lo que sucede en la segunda imagen, que esta fuera de la función.
[image: Funciones que si se muestran]

¿Existe alguna forma de solucionar esto o sera que siempre es asi? La consulta viene a que llego a pensar que si no aparece, es porque mi código esta malo.

Codigo completo:

```js
var nombres = ['John', 'Kenny', 'Tom', "Bob", 'Dilan'];

function manipulacionNombres(personas){

   return personas; //Aqui esperaba que me apareciera personas.sort();

}

console.log(manipulacionNombres(nombres));
```

Comment: visual studio o visual studio code?